# chmod doesn't work in exec in java

Tags: java, linux, exec, file-permissions, chmod

I'm changing file permission with this code:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod 600 '/home/user/Desktop/file'");
```

But it has no effect!
Before and after code execution `ls -l /home/user/Desktop/file` reports:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 evir evir 7928 Jul 31 14:54 file
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Probably the command returns an error and you're not capturing it. Does the directory exist? does the user you're running the command has priviledged to change the permissions on that file?

Comment: u should check this http://www.coderanch.com/t/358380/Servlets/java/Chmod-Runtime-Exec

Comment: @Augusto: yes directory (and file) exists (As I checked before execution); Yes application is running as "evir" that file belongs to him!

Comment: Try testing what the return code is. `Process p = runtime.getRuntime()...`, wait for completion `p.waitFor()` and check `p.exitValue()`.

Comment: @sreejith: I'm checking permisions from OS and it is not changed!!! Nevertheless I tried `waitFor()` and it has no effect!

Comment: @DuncanJones: you're right it is exiting with code 1 ! I checked ErrorStream and found that does single quotes made not found error! removing them solved problem! does `exec` automatically cast chars? (e.g. spaces)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question you asked is very specific to your system and environment.

So I'll answer the broader question - and teach a man to fish - by pointing out that you should look at the output in order to determine what happened (or didn't).

First up, you should assign the `Process` instance returned from `exec` to a variable.  Fire-and-forget is nice when it works, but if it doesn't you're left with absolutely no way to determine what's happened.

First stop is to call `process.waitFor()` - which waits for the process to finish, and returns you its exit code.  If this is non-zero it didn't run correctly; and depending on the process this may even tell you what class of error was encountered.

If this is not sufficient to solve your problem, you'll want to see what was output to `stdout` and `stderr`.  You can get handles to read these streams by calling `process.getInputStream()` and `process.getErrorStream()` respectively.  Once you have these streams, just read bytes from them as normal.

(Note that you really ought to read from these streams as a matter of course, whether you intend to process the data or not.  Processes that write enough output to fill the buffer may otherwise block until the "other end" (you!) has read some of it down.  With your `chmod` example though that's unlikely to be the problem.)

---

Now you have access to the exit status, stdout and stderr streams - in fact everything you'd get if you ran the process within a console.  All that remains now is to use that information to solve your specific issue...

Comment: Thanks; I checked ErrorStream and found that does single quotes made not found error! removing them solved problem! does exec automatically cast chars? (e.g. spaces)

Comment: The quotes are actually a shell-specific construct, to help it with tokenising your command into arguments.  Java doesn't parse the command line like this and hence takes quotes literally.  You would probably be better off using the version of `exec` which takes a string *array*; each element of the array is one argument (no worries about spaces or escaping), so this would work even if the path had spaces in, whereas your current workaround would not.

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't it be more simple to do:

```
    File file = new File("/home/user/Desktop/file");
    file.setReadable(true, true);
    file.setWritable(true, true);
    file.setExecutable(false, false);
```

That way you avoid getting into the system-specific command line calls...